# Why does rlang::quo_is_missing(quo(NA)) evaluate to FALSE?

Tags: r, rlang

If I understand, rlang::quo_is_missing evaluates a quosure and checks whether it contains a missing value. If it does, it should return TRUE, FALSE if not. Yet, I've tried the following combinations and it always returns FALSE:

```
rlang::quo_is_missing(quo(NA))
rlang::quo_is_missing(quo(NA_character_))
rlang::quo_is_missing(quo(NA_integer_))
```

If I try non-NA values, it also returns FALSE, as expected:

```
rlang::quo_is_missing(quo("hello"))
```

Why is it returning FALSE when the value is obviously missing?

Comment: quo_is_missing does not check for NAs, It checks for quosures that contain the missing argument. See the examples at https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quosure.html.

Comment: Yes, but the quosure that I provide as argument (quo(NA)) contains NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Missing" is a special term that refers to values that are not present at all. `NA` is not the same as "missing" -- `NA` is itself a value. In base R you can compare the functions `is.na()` and `missing()` each of which do different things. `quo_is_missing` is like the `missing()` function, not `is.na` and returns true only when there is no value at all:

```
rlang::quo_is_missing(quo())
```

If you want to check for NA, you could write a helper

```
quo_is_na <- function(x) {
    !rlang::quo_is_symbolic(x) && 
      !rlang::quo_is_missing(x) && 
      !rlang::quo_is_null(x) &&
      is.na(rlang::quo_get_expr(x))
}
quo_is_na(quo())
# [1] FALSE
quo_is_na(quo(x+y))
# [1] FALSE
quo_is_na(quo(NULL))
# [1] FALSE
quo_is_na(quo(42))
# [1] FALSE

quo_is_na(quo(NA))
# [1] TRUE
quo_is_na(quo(NA_character_))
# [1] TRUE
```